# I don`t understand recursion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I don't understand this!

```
function rec(arg){
    console.log(arg);
    if(arg == 3)
        return arg;
    else 
        rec(arg + 1);
}

var i = rec(0);
console.log(i);
//0
//1
//2
//3
//undefined
```

Why inside the function 'arg' has a value but when it`s time to return it('arg == 3') it gives me 'undefined'?

Here is another one

```
function power(base, exponent) {
 console.log(exponent);
 if (exponent == 0)
   return 1;
 else
   return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}

console.log(power(2, 3));
//3
//2
//1
//0
//8
```

Why does it return '8' when 'exponent' is '0' inside the function and it should return '1'!

I now understand that I don`t understand how JS works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, you should write the line

> if(arg == 3)return arg;else rec(arg + 1);

as this

> if(arg == 3)return arg;else **return** rec(arg + 1);

In the second example, you should change the line

> return base * power(base, exponent - 1);

to

> return Math.pow(base, exponent);

(actually, you should just replace the whole function with a call to pow(), you don't need to re-write it)

EDIT:
In the first example, you should have broken it town into multiple lines, then you would have seen it as a simple mistake.  So, like this:

```
if(arg == 3)
  return arg;
else 
  return rec(arg + 1);
```

And for posterity and good habits, it should be like this (in other words, use brackets)

```
if(arg == 3) {
  return arg;
}
else {
  return rec(arg + 1);
}
```

In your second example, you used recursion when you shouldn't have.  A simple call to Math.pow() was all that you needed.  Unless you wanted to log the behavior, no need to re-write the function.

EDIT:

My mistake after reading your comment.  I apologize.

The flow goes like this:

console.log(power(2, 3));

then to the line

```
if (3 == 0)
   return 1;
else
   return 2 * power(2, 3 - 1);  //power() returns 4, we return 8
   //same as: return 2 * power(2, 2);
```

then to the line

```
if (2 == 0)
   return 1;
else
   return 2 * power(2, 2 - 1);  //power() returns 2, we return 4
   //same as: return 2 * power(2, 1);
```

then to the line

```
if (1 == 0)
   return 1;
else
   return 2 * power(2, 1 - 1);  //power() returns 1, we return 2
   //same as: return 2 * power(2, 0);
```

then to the line

```
if (0 == 0)
   return 1;
else
   // moot
```

Comment: The second one is a valid function.I just didnt get why it works.And yes i know that I that i don`t have to re-write pow.I was giving an example that I don`t understand.

Comment: power(2, 3) would have been this:

2 * (2^(3-1))

...which is 2 * (2 ^ 2)

...which is 2 * 4

...which is 8

If you had returned power(2,3) and defined it as 

return power(base, exponent );

you would be fine.

Comment: Thank you!Kind sir!

Answer (score 3):

Because your not telling it to.

```
function rec(arg){
     console.log(arg);
     if(arg == 3)return arg;
     else rec(arg + 1);        // < --- not a return statement
}
var i = rec(0);console.log(i);
```

The `else` block is not a return statement.

And as for your second question, that is because the `0` is coming from a nested call to the function somewhere down the line:

```
base * power(base, exponent - 1);  // power(base, exponent - 1) would return 1 here, and base is probably 8 at that moment, so 8 * 1 would return you 8
```

Comment: I thought I told it to in the line 'if (arg == 3) RETURN arg;'

Comment: it is only told to return the first time around, at 0. The second, third, and fourth calls will never be returned to sender.

Comment: Think about it, you sent a value of 0 and say if it equals 3 then return, but it doesn't, and there is no more return statements following, so there is nothing left to return.

Comment: The following recursive calls only end up returning the value to the previous method call, but the value never makes it back out of the original method call.

Answer (score 1):

While the previous answers give factually correct information, they don't address what you're misunderstanding.

In both cases, you're expecting the return form the recursive function to be the return of the last (innermost) invocation.  That's incorrect.

The return from the innermost invocation is given to the second-to-innermost invocation; and then this continues until finally the outermost invocation returns.  Only the outermost invocation's return value is seen by the caller.

So in the first example, you call `rec(0)`.
Then `rec(0)` calls `rec(1)`, 
which calls `rec(2)`, 
which calls `rec(3)`.

Then `rec(3)` returns the value `3` to `rec(2)` (because that's still running).
Then `rec(2)` exits without a return to `rec(1)`
which exits without a return to `rec(0)`
which exits without a return to the caller.

So the caller sees the return as undefined.

In the second case, yes, the last invocation of `power()` is `power(2,0)` which returns 1... to the running invocation of `power(2,1)`
which returns 2 to the running invocation of `power(2,2)`

... and so on until the final return seen by the caller is 8.

By the way, this is not "recursion in JavaScript".  This is recursion.